# Does the second law of thermodynamics has any part to play in the expansion of universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, universe

This is a question out of curiosity and I am not a physics expert. As far as I understand "Entropy keeps on increasing in a closed system" is one of the statements for second law of thermodynamics. So my question is the following: *Does the second law of thermodynamics has any part to play in the never ending expansion of universe?*

Can I think this way: Since the universe is expanding, the particles in the system too are moving towards an equilibrium. I don't know if a closed system can be expanding. I am also unclear whether to use the term isolated or closed here for system.

Comment: one comment **Does the second law of thermodynamics has any part to play in the never ending expansion of universe** we don't understand the expansionary force, so we don't know if it is never ending.  (although it probably is......) I am not being pedantic, just in case it affects your question.

Answer (score 1):

Closed system is a system that has a wall that you can pass heat and work to the system but not matter.

Isolated system is a system that you cannot even pass heat and work.

2nd law states that the entropy will always no decreasing for an isolated system.

Entropy describes the possible states in a system. If the space increases, at least you know there will be more states (e.g. a particle has more positions to occupy). Thus more entropy.